# Boiling is not well described?

Tags: pressure, physical-chemistry, evaporation

It is said that boiling occurs only when the vapour pressure becomes equal to the pressure surrounding the vapour (say atmospheric pressure).

Why does it take place only satisfying these conditions ? They say that it is only in this condition that equilibrium between phases takes place.

If so, doesn't the continued heat supply cause a change in the equilibrium ??

Comment: Seems to be very similar to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/144468/

Comment: Could you please explain the answer ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do liquids boil when their vapor pressure equals the ambient pressure?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/129512/)

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find the answer for my question anywhere.

Comment: "Why does it take place only satisfying these conditions?" -- this is answered in the link I gave. Read clark599's comment to Whelp's answer.

Comment: A continued heat supply does not cause a change in the equilibrium since the more heat you supply, the faster the water boils, thus removing an equivalent amount of heat, and maintaining the equilibrium. Alternatively, if the steam is trapped, then the pressure increases, but that would change the vapor pressure, and again balance out in equilibrium.

Comment: @dmckee - while not unrelated, I think the questions are different: the one you link to asks about "steady state" and this one asks about "boiling".

Comment: "Equilibrium between phases" is not thermodynamic equilibrium. It  probably means the  the pause in  temperature, constant at 100C,  until the liquid is completely depleted and all the mass is in the steam phase.

Comment: @user2813274 how can it get balanced since the atmospheric pressure is constant.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not "equilibrium" - the issue is **boiling**.

During boiling, there is explicitly NO equilibrium: the water wants to get out of the liquid phase, and into the vapor phase. The temperature of the liquid is sufficiently high that liquid can evaporate below the surface (strictly speaking the temperature must be slightly above boiling for that, as the pressure below the surface is above ambient pressure) and form bubbles. As these bubbles rise, they expand - and at the surface, they release their vapor into the atmosphere.

There is no "equilibrium" here - as the liquid continues to be heated, it continues to evaporate. And unless the atmosphere above the liquid is emptied of all species other than water vapor, the process will continue more in the forward (evaporation) direction than the reverse (condensation) direction: the definition of "not in equilibrium".

At temperatures below boiling, the rate at which liquid escapes and becomes vapor ultimately becomes the same as the rate at which vapor condenses back into the liquid. That's when equilibrium is possible - although not always attained. It depends on the degree of circulation of (dry) air above the liquid.

So I would say you were right - your question

> doesn't the continued heat supply cause a change in the equilibrium

can be answered with "YES". There is no equilibrium during boiling.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It will be more helpful if u can answer this too. If there is no equilibrium attaining, why cant boiling take place other than this situation.

Comment: "boiling" is the spontaneous formation of a bubble of vapor. This needs the pressure inside the bubble to be greater than atmospheric pressure. That can only happen when the temperature is such that the partial vapor pressure is >= atmospheric. The bubbles you see before boiling ("kettle singing") are typically dissolved gases escaping - or cases where the wall is locally hot enough, but the liquid is not, so that the rising bubble cools and its content (the vapor) is (partially) re-absorbed.

Comment: If the atmospheric pressure and vapour pressure are equal, then boiling takes place. I am asking why this is the condition since nothing (like equilibrium) special is happening here also.

Comment: The vapor cannot create a bubble against atmospheric pressure unless the temperature is high enough. This is the difference between evaporation (a bit of vapor "sneaks out" into the atmosphere above - but the partial pressure of water in the atmophere is less than 1 atm) and boiling (a bubble of pure vapor of sufficient pressure to exist by itself is created - it must have a partial vapor pressure of >= 1 atm to do so).